# Make a page with placeholders that are populated according to a row of data from a list. SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

In Classic ASP I was able to make place holders on a page and then populate them from a database.
I would then have a standard page that would then be populated by that row of data depending on the URL parameters.
Is there a way to do something similar where I populate the placeholder from a list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do this dynamically:

- [Content search webpart](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/Configure-a-Content-Search-Web-Part-in-SharePoint-0dc16de1-dbe4-462b-babb-bf8338c36c9a)
- Custom HTML/Javascript display using [Javascript Client Object Model or REST API for data retrieval](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/mt210455.aspx)
- [Content by query webpart](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650512.aspx)

There's no easy way to do this if you want to generate static versions of pages based on the list values, you would need to use the CSOM or a Powershell script to loop through your list values and generate pages or something similar.

Comment: Thanks for replying John.
I wouldn't need to loop through thankfully. I would just like to make a newscaster page with as header, body and a few pictures all from list items from a particular row. But I am lost in how to call the aforementioned in and link them to the appropriate place on the page. Furthermore what webparts do I use to call the header, body and image. I am not a total newb, I am just a little lost. Sincere thanks for any help,